# Closing a nested stream closes its parent streams too?

Tags: java, stream, nested

```java
OutputStream fos;
OutputStream bos;
OutputStream zos;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(anyFile);
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
} finally {
    if (zos != null) {
        zos.close(); // + exception handling
    }
}
```

Does closing `zos` automatically closes `bos` and `fos` too, or do I need to close them manually?

Comment: You should also be careful to *always* close the outermost stream; otherwise you may experience data loss due to unflushed buffers in wrapper streams which got their wrapped stream closed under their nose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it does. Its [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#close%28%29) says:

> Closes the ZIP output stream as well as the stream being filtered.

Also, the [Javadoc for `BufferedOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#close%28%29) says:

> Closes this output stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream.
>
> The `close` method of `FilterOutputStream` calls its `flush` method, and then calls the `close` method of its underlying output stream.

So when you close your `ZipOutputStream`, it will close your `BufferedOutputStream`, which will in turn close your `FileOutputStream`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

[`ZipOutputStream.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#close%28%29) method is specified by [`Closeable.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close%28%29) which:

> Closes this stream and releases any system resources associated with
>   it.

The same applies to [`BufferedOutputStream.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#close%28%29), a method inherited from `FilterOutputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

*Closing the wrapper stream automatically closes the inner stream.*

So, in your case you only need to close `ZipOutputStream`. Closing a stream twice does not throw an exception hence closing an inner stream again (although unnecessary) works as well.

Here's what happens when you instantiate a `ZipOutputStream`

```
public ZipOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
    this.out = out; // BufferedOutputStream reference saved
}
```

Here's the implementation of `ZipOutputStream.close()`

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    try {
      flush();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
    out.close(); // BufferedOutputStream being closed
}
```

Similarly, `BufferedOutputStream` automatically closes the `FileOutputStream` through its inherited `FilterOutputStream#close()` which has been implemented as:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    try {
      flush();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
    out.close(); // FileOutputStream being closed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. but strangely when i was running the fortify scan with find bug enabled it catches all these kind of  wrapped and unclosed streams as high priority items to be fixed. Not sure why they do so