# java.io.IOException: Stream closed ZipInputStream

Tags: java, zip, zipinputstream

Below is the code Snippet.

```
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
    ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
    ZipEntry entry = null;
    String routerListUCM = "";

    try {
        entries:

        while ((entry = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            if (entry.getName().startsWith("routes")) {

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zin, "UTF-8"));

                if (true) {
                    //parse the xml of the route...

                    DOMParser dp = new DOMParser();

                    dp.parse(in);
                    Element e = (Element) dp.getDocument().getFirstChild();

                    String transferid = e.getElementsByTagName("transferId").item(0).getTextContent();
                    System.out.println("transferId=" + transferid);
                    int fileid = Integer.parseInt(transferid.split("-")[1]);
                    System.out.println("fileid=" + transferid);
                    String userList = e.getElementsByTagName("userList").item(0).getTextContent();
                    System.out.println("userList=" + userList);
                    String routeList = e.getElementsByTagName("routeList").item(0).getTextContent();
                    System.out.println("routeList=" + routeList);
                    routerListUCM = routeList;

                    if (routeList.toLowerCase().indexOf(myname().toLowerCase()) == -1) {
                        //my server is not in the current route...
                        //so skip this route table.
                        continue entries;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

in some cases after "continue entries;" and trying for next loop i see "stream close Exception" :/

```
error:Stream closed
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.ensureOpen(ZipInputStream.java:67)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:116)
at org.parsisys.test.mina.view.SimpleFtplet$beaVersion0_1155.isTransferFinished(SimpleFtplet.java:299)
at org.parsisys.test.mina.view.SimpleFtplet.isTransferFinished(SimpleFtplet.java)
at org.parsisys.test.mina.view.SimpleFtplet.beaAccessisTransferFinished(SimpleFtplet.java)
at org.parsisys.test.mina.view.SimpleFtplet$beaVersion0_1155.onUploadEnd(SimpleFtplet.java:208)
at org.parsisys.test.mina.view.SimpleFtplet.onUploadEnd(SimpleFtplet.java)
at org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.DefaultFtplet.afterCommand(DefaultFtplet.java:89)
at org.parsisys.test.mina.view.SimpleFtplet.afterCommand(SimpleFtplet.java)
at org.apache.ftpserver.ftpletcontainer.impl.DefaultFtpletContainer.afterCommand(DefaultFtpletContainer.java:144)
at org.apache.ftpserver.impl.DefaultFtpHandler.messageReceived(DefaultFtpHandler.java:220)
at org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpHandlerAdapter.messageReceived(FtpHandlerAdapter.java:61)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:716)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:434)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:796)
at org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter.messageReceived(FtpLoggingFilter.java:85)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:434)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:796)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:75)
at org.apache.mina.filter.logging.MdcInjectionFilter.filter(MdcInjectionFilter.java:136)
at org.apache.mina.filter.util.CommonEventFilter.messageReceived(CommonEventFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:434)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:796)
at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter$ProtocolDecoderOutputImpl.flush(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:427)
at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:245)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:434)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:796)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:75)
at org.apache.mina.core.session.IoEvent.run(IoEvent.java:63)
at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:780)
at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTasks(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:772)
at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:714)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Please Help Me....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your outermost `BufferedReader` object closes your nested streams (in particular `ZipInputStream`). Try to move your BufferedReader initalization code higher the looping logic.

Also this topic might be helpful: [closing nested streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054184/closing-a-nested-stream-closes-its-parent-streams-too).

**Update:**
Ok, now everything is clear. Implementation code of `DOMParser` class shows clearly that `parse` method closes underlying `InputStream` source (just an excerpt of finally block):

```
} finally {
    this.parser.reader.close();
}
```

What can be done in this situation is hacking your `BufferedReader` which is passed to `DOMParser` object. Here's an example:

```
public class HackedReader extends BufferedReader {

    public HackedReader(InputStreamReader inputStreamReader) {
        super(inputStreamReader);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // Close method doesn't do anything, that's the main sense of overriding.
    }

    // But you know exact method which will close your underlying stream.
    public void hackedClose() throws IOException {
        super.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have Done it ... But Steal Have Stream Closed problem :(

Comment: @Namira Can you please tell me fully qualified name of your `DOMParser` class? It seems that problem is related to parsing functionality of that class.

Comment: oracle.xml.parser.v2.DOMParser  tnx

Comment: @Namira please look at the update section. This should fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

I found using the `org.apache.poi.util.CloseIgnoringInputStream` worked for me. I was able to wrap the `ZipInputStream` that I was passing into another method.

For example:

```
ExcelUtility.getLineCount(new CloseIgnoringInputStream(zipStream)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can implemet a logic to understand if there aren't more "routes" to read, at the end of `If` block you can insert a `break` instruction to exit the while block and avoid to attempt to read the closed stream